# How to apply QFT to the last two qubits of a Qiskit quantum circuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, quantum-fourier-transform

I'm pretty new in Qiskit and quantum circuits. I'm using Qiskit to implement a quantum circuit and I followed this [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html) to implement a QFT. The way this QFT was built, it applies QFT in the first $n$ qubits, but what I need is to apply the QFT in the last $n$ qubits. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, to build a Quantum Fourier Transform on an arbitrary number of qubits, you can use the [QFT class](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QFT.html) already implemented in Qiskit.
In particular, to apply it to the last two qubits of your circuit, you can convert the QFT object to a gate and then append it passing the qubits indices.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qft = QFT(num_qubits=2).to_gate()
qc.append(qft, qargs=[1, 2])

qc.decompose(reps=2).draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this pretty straightforward answer! Could you please edit your question and add some comments about how to do the same to an inverse QFT?

Comment: To get the inverse QFT, you just need `qft_inv = qft.inverse()`; more in general, given an arbitrary quantum gate defined in Qiskit, you can compute its inverse operation by calling the method [`Gate.inverse`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.inverse.html).